# Error performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send a email everytime a user is created, but I just can't. I've follow many tutorials and topics of the same error.
I tried this on console too and the same happend:

```
TesteMailer.welcome_email(User.first).deliver_later
```

and it returns:

> Error performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: e536b95d-fab5-4f9d-82ac-b2af12336fc2) from Async(mailers) in 10485.78ms: EOFError (end of file reached):

I also tried

```
TesteMailer.welcome_email(User.first).deliver_now
```

or just

```
TesteMailer.welcome_email(User.first).deliver
```

and both returns

> EOFError: end of file reached

Here is my SMTP config:

```
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
   port:                 465,
   domain:               'gmail.com',
   user_name:            '...@gmail.com',
   password:             '...',
   authentication:       'plain',
   enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

I also tried using SMPT Port 587 and replacing

```
config.action_mailer
```

by

```
ActionMailer::Base
```

**I'm using Ruby 2.3.3p222 and Rails 5.1.2**

## **EDIT**

The same occour in Heroku

> 2017-12-08T19:46:26.548061+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2017-12-08T19:46:26.547992 #4] ERROR -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [52dac876-c9a0-4c69-958b-0c08ec75f2af] Error performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 52dac876-c9a0-4c69-958b-0c08ec75f2af) from Async(mailers) in 10548.59ms: EOFError (end of file reached):

Comment: show your TesteMailer code.

Comment: Could you please share your Mailer code.

Comment: Possible issue could be that your `from` address set for the mailer is invalid. So see if you have set a valid `from` address if you have not, the default would be `example.com` which is why it could be failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding:

```
gem 'mail', '~> 2.7'** to the Gemfile
```

Comment: Could you, please, clarify - you just added the line to your Gemfile or you also did any further setup?

Comment: I don't remember, I think I only added this line and ran the bundle

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks anyway!

Comment: FYI, I'm still getting this `EOFError (end of file reached)` error with `mail` version `2.7.1`. So I don't think this is the solution.

Comment: how did any of you solved it ?